# Bootstrap 3 Signin form and jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3 Signin form. But when I add jQuery Validation Plugin it starts to jump. So the problem is: 1. I type Login (correct) 2. Than I click Password to type it, but Password's form is jumping down.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please use only a-z0-9_-");
$('#form-signin').validate({
    rules: {
        login: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        password: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

### **[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4pmUW/)**

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me *(Google Chrome on Ubuntu Linux)*.

Comment: Your OP should also show the relevant HTML markup.  Otherwise, when the links go dead, this question is useless to others.

Comment: [Your jsFiddle is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/condpattern/sTDcF/3/).  Clicking submit does not invoke any validation at all.  Your fiddle includes a very ancient copy of jQuery Validate... 1.52.  Have you tried using the latest version?  Version 1.11.1 seems to be working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/sTDcF/4/

Comment: @condpattern Sparky is right, your fiddle's submit does nothing! Refer his code.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks, I corrected JSFIDDLE as your example. I hope it's working now.

Comment: @Yoda No need to click submit, forms should checking before submit.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. I hope now my example is working. So the problem is:
1. I type Login (correct)
2. Than I click  Password to type it, but Password's form is jumping down.
Why it's going on?

Comment: Please edit your question with the better problem description from your last comment.  Thanks

Comment: @Sparky As you said problem was >An empty label element is being added under the login field... Your solution is working. A lot of thanks!

Comment: What I meant is, these questions and answers are also here to help future visitors.  It would make more sense if the following comment was edited into your original question.  _"So the problem is: 1. I type Login (correct) 2. Than I click Password to type it, but Password's form is jumping down."_  ~ Never mind, I'll put it into my answer.

Comment: Just in case, I edited my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quote OP's comment:**

> *"So the problem is: 1. I type Login (correct) 2. Than [sic] I click Password
>   to type it, but Password's form is jumping down."*

Using the DOM inspector, I see one thing changing when data is entered into the first field...

An empty `label` element is being added under the login field...

```
<label for="login" class="error"></label>
```

This is the default `label` that is automatically created by the plugin.

I've isolated down to your `success` callback function.  Removing it makes it work without the "jump".

http://jsfiddle.net/sTDcF/7/

Instead of `success`, I think you should use the `unhighlight` callback function.  The `unhighlight` callback is the compliment to the `highlight` callback, so typically you would use them together like this...

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error');
}
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/sTDcF/8/

Comment: @RoLYroLLs, I'm going to delete my comments.